# jQuery can't fire 'change' event using code to mimmic list selection change

Tags: jquery

Got the this function which, to make it short, enables and populates the next drop down list (it calls another jQuery function, but won't post it for now). It works perfectly. Now I'm trying to pass default values and have it enable and populate the following drop downs without actually clicking on anything.

The function that currently works:

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.update', function() {
    formObject.run($(this));
    });
});
```

Here, the 'change' event was used because when the page loads, all lists but the first one are disabled, so a change (Selection of any item) in the first list will enable the second list, a later selection in the second list will enable the third list an so on. formObjet is a variable which contains a function 'run' that does all the 'dirty job'.

Now, I read (been browsing for hours!) that you could call the change event or the trigger handler to mimmic such selection, but none has worked so far:

```
$('select[name="princ"]').change(); // DOES NOT WORK
$('select[name="princ"]').trigger('change'); // DOES NOT WORK EITHER
```

I have placed this code snipped before the function, after, but nothing seems to work. BTW, 'princ' is the first dropdown, which is populated when the page loads (does no depend on javascript to be filled, simply php and mysql)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure the binding and the triggering are targeting the same elements? In one you target `.update` and in the other `[name="princ"]`. This simple example of what you're doing seems to work OK for me: http://jsfiddle.net/95ZnS/ (tested: Opera, Chrome)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding the question, but I think I've dealt with something similar.

Browsers all handle the change event differently and usually doesn't fire until the user clicks away from that field after updating it (by clicking somewhere else on the page and solidifying their change).

My workaround has been to create a function that does the work for me and have that function run on click instead of change.  To cover your bases (and not have dynamic data loading unnecessarily), I would go about it this way:

1. Create global variables or object to track the state of each dropdown (you can store id, value, etc. - this basically alows you to check whether the dropdown.  For default state, create all the variables and set their values to blank)
2. Create a function that runs each time any of the fields are clicked and pass in the dropdown (either through ID, name or the actual jQuery object)

**The JavaScript Portion**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Attach click function to princ
    $("select[name='princ']").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();  // Grab the value
        if (value != demo.globals.princ) {   // Check if the value is the old value
            demo.checkDropdown('princ', 'princ2', value);  // If it's a new value, grab the selected value and run the checkDropdown function
            demo.globals.princ = value;  // Set the global value
            $('#status').text("loading new values for princ " + value);
        } else {
            $('#status').text("princ values already loaded " + value);  // Unnecessary but used to output the status of the clicks
        }
    });
    // Attach click function to princ2
    $("select[name='princ2']").click(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();
        if (value != demo.globals.princ2) {
            demo.checkDropdown('princ2', 'princ3', value);
            demo.globals.princ2 = value;
            $('#status').text("loading new values for princ2 " + value);
        } else {
            $('#status').text("princ2 values already loaded " + value);
        }
    });
});
// Create a global object to avoid function collision
var demo = {};
// Create global variables
demo.globals = {
    princ: 0,
    princ2: 0
}
// Dropdown population function
demo.checkDropdown = function(dropDownName, nextDropDown, value) {
    // Check if it's already populated with the correct data, otherwise load it
    // You can also load dynamic data here via AJAX and update the select field
    var dropDownHtml = "<option value='1'>1</option>";
    dropDownHtml += "<option value='2'>2</option>";
    dropDownHtml += "<option value='3'>3</option>";
    $("select[name='" + nextDropDown + "']").html(dropDownHtml);
}
```

**The HTML**

```html
<body>
    <form>
        <div id="status">Page loaded</div>
        <select name="princ">
            <option value="0">Please select one</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>

        <select name="princ2">
        </select>

        <select name="princ3">
        </select>

    </form>
</body>
```

I really hope this helps you out.  It's a little more than what you're asking for, but it is a complete, working example of how to get dropdown values on change.

Comment: Stephan, I've been trying to implement this code, however, it only runs the first time, i.e., it runs the first list and shows the second one, but it doens't run the second itself: it simply doesn't show the third list. This is also evident because the test messages only show when clicking the first list ("loading new values" and "values already loaded"). I used the same code you're showing and adapted it to my needs. Placed it after the html code. Also changed the "demo" declaration to the top of the js code so variables could be recognized by click and showlist functions. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, just fount out that for some reason the "select[name='XXXX']" statements were not working, so I had to write (until now, will solve this issue later) separate dropdown functions for each id ('#princ', '#princ2'...). Now the lists are working properly, showing what they're supposed to show, BUT for some reason list No.2 (princ2) is not passing its value, but I can get the values from "princ" and "princ3, weird behaviour, have revised the code in depth but found nothing out of the ordinary so far... will keep looking...

Comment: Hi there.  Sorry you're still having problems with it.  Any way you can get your entire code block to me so I can take a look at it as a whole and help you troubleshoot? :)  You can send it to my email and I'll update the post here for the community.

Comment: Stephan, here's the sample: http://eduardoarria.comze.com. WHen values are not passed (?val1=1&val2=4, etc...) it works perfectly. When values are passed and therefore trigger.click() is called, you can notice that the third dropdown is not generated, i.e., the click function for the second dropdown is not called. you can edit the files here: http://members.000webhost.com/login.php, email: eoarria@gmail.com, Password: eddievh1, then go to cPanel (Action section), file manager icon. Index.php file is located in public_html folder.

Comment: Eduardo, I checked out your site and the code I wrote above works flawlessly in there - the piece that is not working are the other functions - there are some critical javascript errors and possibly errors in the PHP returning the JSON.  Please mark this question as answered and create a new one for the new issues.

Comment: New issue posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11388175/jquery-only-first-of-two-click-events-runs-when-doing-it-using-click-trig

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what browser you're using to test, the change event may not be bubbling up to the document level:
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html

Your example would not work in IE8 and below.

Comment: Not about trigger or triggerHandler, however the information in the page indicates that change is only possible via mouse click or keyboard. I'll try to recode to see what happens. Thanks for the feedback!