# jQuery: Only first of two .click() events runs when doing it using .click, .trigger()

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I think I've seen a lot of similar questions to mine, but I have found no answer so far. I adapted some dependent drop downs found on the web, which work perfectly when clicked by the user: You click on the first list (select) and when you choose an item that has "children", these show on a second drop down and so on. The problem began when I wanted to pass default values. The first list got its value, nu problem. Then, to generate the second drop down I added a .click() event to the corresponding Id. It actually shows the second drop down and also the selected element (passed from the drop down populating function). HOWEVER, once loaded, no matter how many actual clicks or code mimmicking clicks, the second drop down does not run it's click function, it onle lets you select, but does not generate a third drop down, which, when not passing any values, works perfectly.

What could be wrong?

Here's the main JS code, which is located just before the body of the page:

```
var demo = {};

demo.globals = {
princ: 0,
princ2: 0,
princ3: 0
}

$(document).on('ready', function() {

$(document).on('click', '#lprinc', function() {
     var value = $(this).val();
      if (value==0){
            $('#lprinc2').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#lprinc2').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden'});
      } 
      else{ 
            $('#lprinc2').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#lprinc2').css({ 'visibility': 'visible'});
            $('#lprinc3').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#lprinc3').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden'});                           
            if (value != demo.globals.princ) {
            demo.checkDropdown('princ', 'princ2', value, val2);
            demo.globals.princ = value;
            } 
    }
});

 if (val1!=''){
            $('#lprinc').trigger('click');
}

$(document).on('click','#lprinc2', function() {
     var value = $(this).val();
      if (value==0){
            $('#lprinc3').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
            $('#lprinc3').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden'});
      } 
      else{ 
            $('#lprinc3').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('#lprinc3').css({ 'visibility': 'visible'});       
            if (value != demo.globals.princ2) {
            demo.checkDropdown1('princ2', 'princ3', value, val3);
            demo.globals.princ2 = value;
            }
     }
 });

if (val2!=''){
         $('#lprinc2').trigger('click');
}    
if (val3!=''){
         $('#princ3').val(val3);
}     

}); 

demo.checkDropdown = function(dropDownName, nextDropDown, value, valorpass) {
jQuery.getJSON('/mod/update.php', { id : nextDropDown, value : value, val: valorpass}, function(data) {
    if (!data.error) {
        $('#lprinc2').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#lprinc2').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#lprinc2').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden'});
        $('#lprinc3').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#lprinc3').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden'});
    }
});    
$("select[name='" + nextDropDown + "']").html(dropDownHtml);

}

demo.checkDropdown1 = function(dropDownName, nextDropDown, value, valorpass) {
jQuery.getJSON('/mod/update.php', { id : nextDropDown, value : value, val: valorpass}, function(data) {
    if (!data.error) {
        $('#lprinc3').html(data.list).removeAttr('disabled');
    } else {
        $('#lprinc3').html('<option value="">----</option>').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#lprinc3').css({ 'visibility': 'hidden'});
    }
});     

$('#lprinc3').html(dropDownHtml);
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I have tried .one, .trigger(), .triggerHandler(), .click() to no avail. I have been going nuts overt his one...

Added: update.php:

```
if (!empty($_GET['value'])) {

$value = $_GET['value'];
$valor= $_GET['val'];

try {

    $objDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=XXXXX', 'XXXXX', 'XXXXX');
    $objDb->exec('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');

    $sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM `categories`
            WHERE `master` = ?";

    $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);
    $statement->execute(array($value));
    $list = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if (!empty($list)) {

        $out = array('<option value="0">Seleccione...</option>');

        foreach($list as $row) {
            $selstrg = "<option value='".$row['id']."' ";
            if ($row['id']==$valor){
                $selstrg = $selstrg." selected ='selected' ";   
            }       
            $selstrg = $selstrg.">".$row['name']."</option>";
            $out[] = $selstrg;          
        }

        echo json_encode(array('error' => false, 'list' => implode('', $out)));

    } else {
        echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
}

} else {
echo json_encode(array('error' => true));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Updated Answer:**

I think you need to update the jQuery events to `on`.

Update code like:

```
$('#princ2').click(function() {
```

To:

```
$('#princ2').on('click', function() {
```

Also the example at http://eduardoarria.comze.com/ shows the error `dropDownHtml is not defined` there is a problem with the following line of code:

```
$("select[name='" + nextDropDown + "']").html(dropDownHtml);
```

Your attempting to use `dropDownHtml` which has not been declared or assigned. Remove the lines of code that attempt to set the HTML to `dropDownHtml`.

Comment: Jon, val3 issued corrected, thanks for the observation. It's no possible to upload it to jsfiddle as lists are populated from a DB and in order to adapt it I would have to change the code, which would miss the whole point, but thanks nonetheless. all "val's" get values from $valX=$_GET['valX'] and passed to js using valX=<?php echo $valX;?>. It seems as if the problem was based on the trigger and click events generated by code. THe order of action is: 1. verify if val exists, 2. Generate click, 3. pass variable ad generate dropdown and 4. generate click for next list (this is where it fails)

Comment: please see updated answer, are you able to setup a test somewhere online?

Comment: Jon, I'll try to set it sometime. I already added the alerts and it seems that the "change" function for #princ2 is not being called (no alerts received whatsoever). My guess is that once the first .trigger('change') is called, it does not allow for any other 'change' function to be called. I even tested only passing val1 so that the second list is generated: the change function for list 2 does not run at all.

Comment: Jon, here's the sample: http://eduardoarria.comze.com. WHen values are not passed (?val1=1&val2=4, etc...) it works perfectly. When values are passed and therefore trigger.click() is called, you can notice that the third dropdown is not generated, i.e., the click function for the second dropdown is not called. you can edit the files here: http://members.000webhost.com/login.php, email: eoarria@gmail.com, Password: eddievh1, then go to cPanel (Action section), file manager icon. Index.php file is located in public_html folder.

Comment: I'll check it out and get back to you on this. Please make sure that those login details are only temporary for your security.

Comment: Yeap, temporary, it's a free site, just for testing :)

Comment: Have you tried this yet, did it resolve your issue (if so please mark this as the answer)?

Comment: JonWamerNet, sorry for the delay to answer. I'm currently behind a firewall and cannot access the web version of the sample to edit it. However, I do not get any erros with dropDownHtml, it runs fine when no arguments are passed. As soon as I pass an argument (click or change event triggered by code) the events for the second and third dropdown do not run. I'm honestly throwing the towel on this one, too long, no solution. Will try to recode the entire thing. Thanks!